# How to compose a string literal from constexpr char arrays at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I'm trying to create a constexpr function that concatenates const char arrays to one array. My goal is to do this recursively by refering to a specialized variable template `join` that always joins two `const char*`'s . But the compiler doesn't like it and throws an error message that I can't get behind.

I've already checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219660/error-qualified-name-refers-into-a-specialization-of-variable-template) topic but it unfortunately doesn't have a straight up answer.

[Code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACs0gAOqAqETgwe3r7%2BpClpjgIhYZEsMXGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BflxVNRn1jQTFEdGxegoNTS057cM9faXlEgCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbgQAnkmYAPoExEyECofYJhoAgpvbu5gHR8jD%2BKgPT1eZi2DB2Xn2hzcTmGxEwrABL0BaAYw0wqiSxD2TC8RD2aQAXpgIMjhntkAhGgAqBRzQEmADsVheexZe1CBDZXwAInsNIcmc9WXsAO4IOhE6lgMCHLkaOYHRmAoVC6zWPD8pXKlmqyz3DYClX0rmalmwgjLBhsjWIo10l4ETAsJIGB1fNwkjnkql7ITtPanc7MNikMkCUle4iUn0Bf1nRisTAI54wrwOPbaVChC54J20a2ve2O51MV2Qj1kimRn1%2B9kAOnrewAkn7yxGo0IY3WG42zEmU2mM1mc87Ib6Q78QCBQlhVBclABHLyMVaQ5v12sPEMd8cEdCT6doueYRfLxNHHvrgEbR42g2syaOZChlEO9GY1uVvYANzES5M8SseJjUZat/wsZt/y5dct17ACe0g6DeQVY19TpW1UMRQtcxLT4yzDT1K3bFt8Irb0OyTD00QxLEcVQdNMwYNC7xZQcGGzXNRz9CcQBYJgAGtLgPWcFyXUEzzcAkiV9Wlrxgnc9x4/jBIYGcjxPMTIUkiAOxkx5r0nH9vETG0UIFQEHWw0tvhIttqxDD8yJjBzI3XH0%2B2uVMOVYi4WC8WhHGdYzXkVZl7waR9n1RN9IoI71DKXbl6NCTiQ283z/LwQLRxjIRL30kB4rPbADN/M8zPQsysOLKz3Rswi7Ji0iq3I69AX7LyGJ8vyAvoFLoyTBlmLxcK8CfSjoucqNCsS1i%2BpavTytMu0C2ecbqOcrEwMgxLzDMBBqlof4zF7DDVvwqj3zqxo9iiLagJ247hRIWh0F2/M1sul8mrJO6eRlA5joQVBhTZBQ2Q5YAGOAQ4ADE3tOwF2T2XjQggWlbxNPYAHosZii68TwQkrgJwlEq4DQ%2BVOoUce%2BqIvCoMDJMg/Nqdx2hhQuVJrjhFhBrpqhx0JxMKuWoVuLQHE3UhJK2PSnrxKYEMonsh4SqMqWjmGhTXDzBGjQ4BZaE4eJeD8DgtFIVBODcHULDxJYVlw4EeFIAhNANhY%2BJADZ6VrLgADYAA4fckDRJHpQONH9/36X0ThJFN93Lc4XgFBADRXfdhY4FgGBEBQVAnXFMgKGJQukmLlADCMK5iC8Bg%2BL4OgHWINOICiJOolCRoTk4F20BYNhBAAeQYWhe/N3gsF4oxxEn0h8FhBw8C/TA0/ntFMGQHE1gt9lqiT2g8CiG5iBODwsCT64cz7g2%2BAMYAFAANTwTBhWHwNb5kQQRDEdgpG/vIJQagk66HaNXYwtt9DHzTpABYqAki1HXgAWl%2BDKUwlhrBcHpKnaoW9aguBUmMNogQVLTAGHEdo%2BR0gCGIXoahtRyFlEGBMPBy8BDdFGJ4VoQw2G1E4b0UI/RmGUNsCMZo3DxhiKmEImYLCFgKAdqsPQ3M1g8ENsbRO88rYcFUIHf2yD/aSDJBAvYEAPIN3lBAG2mDLAhlwIQEgAMNh%2Bg8EXegmJNhcDmLwN2k85iexAJISQtYzDh0kBsQOABOMwgdYlRKiYHOOHAE6kBYAkDOZsLY6NTunTO/jSA53zksAgSQcTkBcPgIgxA8B7naPwH%2BohxAAIaUAlQ6h55gNIMKG4SRb4aI4CbUgWTeA6OHjiMpHJUBUD2HogxRiTGGGAGYixfErFuIrh45x3jfFZwWPtJgWA4ho2Sak9J8RMlJxybYPJfitABNIF7MwUTaz0hidHMw/tIkJODhsDYySNhaOySnfJ9zCl5wgEgNAWAHHVIqdQcUQY1G8Fab/Zp0hWmKHaaA3IECUBQLsPgjIhD3CSL8AEYIsiKESGwXkVINDMhktyAwjITDZhcFpYS9hdRxF0ICFy/h4i2UsM5bypl/KhVUpETS%2BkCilFrDeKCD4boAyXGuLcAgeobxAhBGCCE3xfhOAGsCd44JcJHGhNzeErVMIrRppNYaniNh/WOgACQOnRJ6xAXp7CBiDCkq89gnCWDdTAjBYbw0qmdF8%2BNsS4i0pNGkTFMZIzwIlSmQ1RTiggJKaUzq5QKiGiqWxFh1RUy1ADKwuoWasgZMaUKppMDmmIJaMti1loWWqua2qX1bJjljIGBM9krrNRjKqpF7k64Dk6sOXWUbO0um7Q6/tXZaxNmIr2%2Bq242SCFcvBG1yYPLTqHBxI4/buJCTUqJFc54uB5WwHJLW%2B4VKHhEqeVcZh70DRCoKMKJZRp4wmiO78pVfqDVAnBLgCF6wwTAvBICiENDIXzHWlDVVF1umXRu8MW6Trao%2BjRXEs0MYNpluxEcZ6uK7knLxAS2YX3CWPNe8SWlpKbmjPJGjSl6OqTfRpI4rGzC6VVgVUDJk0PPBpgunCmGR1EWHZuqkrkhBJntedaKca6JpW6pleg2kuCOq3K5FgJBMDo0k7jQagIaZCjNBaMjctdNEhhCGEzsIZIChpqh210mapYYUzhxyFF1PUU0w5nTgV9OOr9B2R1Qnk2kbsy2mWmlrhUeIHhmtLIaYPgAwRjahVfozQYnNTLet60rV80uuTDVl1OTk8pydnlwsZSyiR39LJctjRC59QLVZpr/VmpR1KnVHNZTPTle9as/z5UK%2BViTVXZOKeath2Ko6mvHtlhF3qw3%2BoHqs6RrrgH1o1YG86lLu35ooZFraqTRYMN4WW5SRrB61Mxo07RFr8tSuqcsz%2B6zf2lq2oB/6e7MnHt9fk41PtmWXhvaiutSsRXiMWcLSD2zTb7PeVnX1bitHlK8aY%2B%2BgTQt9O6UfXj7jl6%2BM3okqTnSV5iqiaMvmLztpbu40W5CX7w1/3dfe6Fz73kvzFeSmeqbzOZtRpy0ejk7NOYwh5iDg7qOhTy65rCVgxJ6r80FkTDkkl5QgBuvTC4fN6Z1r15cQaTMjRo9IyqOHuNDQVfR6yKrkJx0JlcgAFS1W7lkX5MzoD2JMiAfvzD%2B0j65RowB5Qq5sxWySxNYQsESsnvYyC2Rm9OonrUEAtqfOZj%2BvPFaWReDSEYPYPv0/UZAFgUQJwriQgb/5OMEBY/Cdz87svrI8AzIIxAC9Cg5wJguF%2BSEPuQzsgePHkvPfe/KgUAwDE7IqDt1N2qC4IZU8hjemYeIr1johk76zhfve617GqEoNkMyh917wCPhQY%2BJ9HCn3sdASwog7ewHPzz5/F9OsV8alBB19%2BYzdLA8Bt89hd8AZewD9QkGZj8sRiA48z9ADtQ7dr9Ph%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%3D%3D):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto size(const char*s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*s!=0) {
        ++i;
        ++s;
    }
    return i;
}

template <const char* S1, typename, const char* S2, typename>
struct join_impl;

template <const char* S1, int... I1, const char* S2, int... I2>
struct join_impl<S1, std::index_sequence<I1...>, S2, std::index_sequence<I2...>>
{
    static constexpr const char value[]{ S1[I1]..., S2[I2]..., 0 };
};

template <const char* S1, const char* S2>
constexpr auto join
{
    join_impl<S1, std::make_index_sequence<size(S1)>, S2, std::make_index_sequence<size(S2)>>::value
};

template <const char* S1, const char* S2, const char*... S>
struct join_multiple
{
    static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, join_multiple<S2, S...>::value>::value;
};

template <const char* S1, const char* S2>
struct join_multiple<S1, S2>
{
    static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, S2>;
};


constexpr const char a[] = "hello";
constexpr const char b[] = "world";
constexpr const char c[] = "how is it going?";

int main()
{
    // constexpr size_t size = 100;
    // char buf[size];
    // lw_ostream{buf, size};

    std::cout << join_multiple<a, b, c>::value << std::endl;
}
```

**Error**:

```
<source>:33:82: error: qualified name refers into a specialization of variable template 'join'
    static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, join_multiple<S2, S...>::value>::value;
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
<source>:25:16: note: variable template 'join' declared here
constexpr auto join
               ^
<source>:33:34: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const char *const'
    static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, join_multiple<S2, S...>::value>::value;
                                 ^
                                       = nullptr
2 errors generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:33:82: error: qualified name refers into a specialization of variable template 'join'
    static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, join_multiple<S2, S...>::value>::value;
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
<source>:25:16: note: variable template 'join' declared here
constexpr auto join
               ^
<source>:33:34: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const char *const'
    static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, join_multiple<S2, S...>::value>::value;
                                 ^
                                       = nullptr
2 errors generated.
Execution build compiler returned:
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative, to avoid to build the temporary char arrays, you might work with types (char sequences) and create the char array variable only at the end, something like:

```
constexpr auto size(const char*s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*s!=0) {
        ++i;
        ++s;
    }
    return i;
}

template <const char* S, typename Seq = std::make_index_sequence<size(S)>>
struct as_sequence;

template <const char* S, std::size_t... Is>
struct as_sequence<S, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = std::integer_sequence<char, S[Is]...>;
};

template <typename Seq>
struct as_string;

template <char... Cs1>
struct as_string<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs1...>>
{
    static constexpr const char c_str[] = {Cs1..., '\0'};
};

template <typename Seq1, typename Seq2, typename... Seqs>
struct join_seqs
{
    using type = typename join_seqs<typename join_seqs<Seq1, Seq2>::type, Seqs...>::type;
};

template <char... Cs1, char... Cs2>
struct join_seqs<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs1...>, std::integer_sequence<char, Cs2...>>
{
    using type = std::integer_sequence<char, Cs1..., Cs2...>;
};

template <const char*... Ptrs>
const auto join =
    as_string<typename join_seqs<typename as_sequence<Ptrs>::type...>::type>::c_str;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ExjzeMa6G)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

First, `join` is a template variable, so it does not contain the so-called `value_type`, it itself is a value, so your `join_multiple` should be

```
template <const char* S1, const char* S2, const char*... S>
struct join_multiple {
  static constexpr const char* value = join<S1, join_multiple<S2, S...>::value>;
};
```

Second and less important, the integer type of `index_sequence` is `size_t` instead of `int`, so the partial specialization of `join_impl` should be (this is not necessary, but using a type other than `size_t` will cause GCC to [reject it incorrectly](https://godbolt.org/z/dqPcoxYhz))

```
template <const char* S1, size_t... I1, const char* S2, size_t... I2>
struct join_impl<S1, std::index_sequence<I1...>, S2, std::index_sequence<I2...>> {
  static constexpr const char value[]{ S1[I1]..., S2[I2]..., 0 };
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ETbs5PEdn)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Looking at my assembly I'm seeing that there's a instance of the `join` variable generated (with its associated string) for every step. Can I somehow avoid that so only the end result string is propagated, maybe by using function templates instead of variable templates?

Comment: "*maybe by using function templates instead of variable templates?*" I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work anyway as partial function template specializations are not allowed :/

Comment: @glades: you might work with type and only at the end create the variable [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ExjzeMa6G)

Comment: @Jarod42: That's exactly what I was looking for! Feel free to write the answer :)